# How to print associative array data in a Smarty template in following scenario?

Tags: php, arrays, smarty, associative-array

I've an array titled `$all_products` in PHP as follows:

```
Array
(

    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 5
            [code] => Ch1212
            [name] => Chesse
            [manufacturer_id] => 33
            [product_type_id] => 35
            [packaging_type_id] => 4
            [created_at] => 1397816303
            [updated_at] => 1397827441
            [manufacturer] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 33
                    [company_name] => Eywa Solutions
                    [email] => shweta.jain@creatywa.com
                    [domain_id] => 14
                    [created_at] => 1397481239
                    [updated_at] => 1397672832
                )

            [product_type] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 35
                    [product_type] => Milk
                    [created_at] => 1397816259
                    [updated_at] => 1397816259
                )

            [packaging_type] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 4
                    [packaging_type] => Pack
                    [bottles_per_pack] => 6
                    [created_at] => 1397641872
                    [updated_at] => 1397672081
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 8
            [code] => LAP201
            [name] => Laptop an
            [manufacturer_id] => 41
            [product_type_id] => 32
            [packaging_type_id] => 5
            [created_at] => 1398088150
            [updated_at] => 1398088150
            [manufacturer] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 41
                    [company_name] => Dell
                    [email] => dell.india@test.com
                    [domain_id] => 8
                    [created_at] => 1397641666
                    [updated_at] => 1397672612
                )

            [product_type] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 32
                    [product_type] => Rum
                    [created_at] => 1397656687
                    [updated_at] => 1397672183
                )

            [packaging_type] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 5
                    [packaging_type] => Case
                    [bottles_per_pack] => 12
                    [created_at] => 1397672031
                    [updated_at] => 1397672031
                )

        )

)
```

The above array is assigned to a smarty template.
Now I've to print the above array in a smarty template. Following is the code I tried to print the array in smarty template but it's displaying only two field's data properly viz. **code and name**. Can you please help me in correcting the error I'm making in printing the rest of the array data in smarty template?

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped">
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th>Sr. No.</th>
                    <th>Manufacturer</th>
                    <th>Product Code</th>
                    <th>Product Name</th>
                    <th>Product Type</th>
                    <th>Packaging Type</th>
                    <th>Action</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                  {assign var='i' value=1}
                  {section name=product loop=$all_products}
                  <tr>
                    <td>{$i}</td>
                    <td>{$all_products[product][manufacturer].comapany_name}</td>
                    <td>{$all_products[product].code}</td>
                    <td>{$all_products[product].name}</td>
                    <td>{$all_products[product][product_type].product_type}</td>
                    <td>{$all_products[product][packaging_type].packaging_type}</td>
                    <td align="center"><a href="{$control_url}products.php?op=edit&id={$all_products[product].id}" ><i class="icon-pencil"></i></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="{$control_url}products.php?op=delete&id={$all_products[product].id}" onClick="return ConfirmDelete()"><i class="icon-trash"></i></a></td>
                  </tr>
                  {assign var='i' value=$i+1}
                  {/section} 
                </tbody>
              </table>
```

From above code the following two statements are displaying the concerned data properly, other lines are displaying nothing:

```
<td>{$all_products[product].code}</td>
<td>{$all_products[product].name}</td>
```

So please help me in displaying the other data properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following code:

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped">
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th>Sr. No.</th>
                    <th>Manufacturer</th>
                    <th>Product Code</th>
                    <th>Product Name</th>
                    <th>Product Type</th>
                    <th>Packaging Type</th>
                    <th>Action</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                  {assign var='i' value=1}
                  {section name=product loop=$all_products}
                  <tr>
                    <td>{$i}</td>
                    <td>{$all_products[product].manufacturer.company_name}</td>
                    <td>{$all_products[product].code}</td>
                    <td>{$all_products[product].name}</td>
                    <td>{$all_products[product].product_type.product_type}</td>
                    <td>{$all_products[product].packaging_type.packaging_type}</td>
                    <td align="center"><a href="{$control_url}products.php?op=edit&id={$all_products[product].id}" ><i class="icon-pencil"></i></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="{$control_url}products.php?op=delete&id={$all_products[product].id}" onClick="return ConfirmDelete()"><i class="icon-trash"></i></a></td>
                  </tr>
                  {assign var='i' value=$i+1}
                  {/section} 
                </tbody>
              </table>
```

You are parsing the array in wrong way. I've corrected it now. It should work for you. Cheers!!!